# ImageJ Fast filters plugin

Tags: image-processing, plugins, image-segmentation, imagej

I've tried using the fast filters plugin - http://imagejdocu.tudor.lu/doku.php?id=plugin:filter:fast_filters:start - by Michael Schmid. But when I integrated it with my own Java program, the results are different even when I used the same parameters I tried in the ImageJ software.

Are there other techniques should be done before feeding it to the plugin?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the fast filters use a **square** or **rectangular kernel**.

The default ImageJ Filters use aproximate circular kernels.

You can view them under `Process -> Filters -> Show Circular Masks`